# How to retrieve the list of results with user id reference in two collections using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections :

```
collection1 : [{
    user_id : '12',
    status : 'active'
},
{
    user_id : '123',
    status : 'active'
}]

collection2 :[{
     user_id :'12',
     item : 'a'
},
{
     user_id :'12',
     item : 'ac'
},
{
     user_id :'12',
     item : 'ab'
}]
```

I want to get list of all users from collection1 along with their count in collection2 as result something like this:
`{user_id :'12', collection2_count :3 , user_id:'123, collection2_count :0}` using mongoose.

I have tried calling it in a loop but that does not seem performance efficient.

Comment: You have duplicated keys in your desired object, you should use an array to separate each one